# Make vim close syntactic construction for code block automatically

Tags: vim, ide, erlang, lua, pascal

Is there plug-in that makes vim close syntactic constructions that wraps code blocks automatically for any language based on data in indent and syntax files?

For example I editing lua file, when I write

```
function myfunction()
```

and press enter it automatically make an closing "end"

```
function myfunction()
    <cursor position>
end
```

Or maybe anyone can show an example how to write your own plug-in for specific language with long keywords for code blocks (like lua, erlang or pascal) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Endwise](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) seems to be what you're looking for. It already has lua support, and it looks like it would be pretty easy to extend, if you are comfortable with VimL.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a snippet plugin like [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) (my favorite) or [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). They essentially expand some small word or piece of text into larger pieces of code and allow you to edit only the parts that are unique for each structure. Both UltiSnips and Snippmate include snippets for many languages and let you create your own snippets.

For example UltiSnips inclueds a function snippet for Lua. I just have to type out `fun` and then press tab and it gets expanded to

```
function new_function(args)

end
```

and `new_fuctnion` gets selected so I can edit the function name. Then once I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> (in my vimrc I rebind this to <kbd>Tab</kbd>) it selects the next part of the snippet which is `args` in this case allowing me to enter the function's arguments. A final <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> puts the cursor in the body of the function.